# Updating Wordpress - 'Philosophical' Question, do you upgrade, or...?

Tags: wordpress

Hi we are at a point in our wordpress website that it would seem appropriate to update the WP version. We have an existing busy site, have paid a good amount to hack plugins and core stuff to get it working the way we want it to. I'm debating the wisdom of updating the entire foundation of the site over a few minor vulnerabilities and enhancements that aren't interesting for us. My thinking is this.

The reason for upgrading appears to be because a given version may have some security issues. So you go through the painful process of updating, which usually kills all your plugins. You then spend many frustrating hours talking to plugin support people telling you 'it must be clashing with other plugins', or you take the time to / pay someone to fix everything (again).

After upgrading you have to take time to relearn the system and all the changes. You may have to adjust your workflow due to these changes, and maybe retrain your entire team. And after all that, in 5 minutes hackers find the security issues with the current version - which MAY be worse than your previous version - and you have to go through the whole operation again.

The aim of running a website is to not spend each and every day dealing with upgrade issues. The aim is to have a system that does what you need it to do, the way you want to do it. Once you have that, it's not useful to keep changing it 'just because', it's not a fashion show. It's not an iPhone, pushing users to upgrade their entire phone because they added a letter on the end of the phone name and changed the color from grey to a slightly different grey.

I am of the opinion that it is much more economical - once you have a system set up the way you need it - to just get a dev to fix any vulnerabilities in your existing WP code. And, somewhere down the line, if there was a VERY good reason you should update (e.g. major new PHP version) - then build the site from scratch and get a dev to migrate the data. This could be 7 years later or more. The time effort and money you would save doing it this way, seems a lot more logical.

Say you were building a Ford Model T in your garage. You are ordering parts from a supplier and you are halfway through the build when your supplier starts sending you parts from a Ford Capri - "Oh we are doing parts for Capris now". So you can the Model T and start building a Capri. Halfway through the build, your supplier starts sending you parts for a Mustang. And so on. You will spend your entire life half building that car and at no point end up driving the C*.

Given the performance issues of WP out the box - and the logical progression of a successful site to start migrating to a bespoke solution - it would make sense to me to take your existing WP, strip out the crap you don't need and optimize everything. At that point, it's not really WP any more, vulnerabilities fixed, and it is essentially already a bespoke solution without needing to start from the absolute ground up.

Does anyone have any thoughts on this? Serious question, we need to decide if we are going to go through all this a 4th time and I'm not really feeling it. Any input would be appreciated thanks. To make this 'it must be a specific question' I will just ask - are you a very experience WP dev, and do YOU keep jumping through the update hoop every 5 mins?

Comment: Well, right out of the gate you have sabotaged yourself by "hack[ing] plugins and core stuff ", so the only advice I can give you is that you should put everything you have so far in a private Git repository, including core files. This is not usually how one would do it, but in your case I would recommend it for backup purposes only.  Afterward you can integrate the "hacks" properly into a new WP installation without touching core files. This  will be critical for you in the future if by chance you ever have to be PCI compliant  .

Comment: Thanks for input - but no, all hacks are well documented and straightforward to move to new versions we have done it before. The issue here isn't 'how do we more efficiently continue to spend all of our time focusing on upgrading things every 5 minutes', but rather, if it is more logical to stop wasting a huge amount of time on it, and focus on actually running the site and making some money instead. I'm in the web business not the WP business.

Comment: In my experience, the only times I've really needed to update anything in WordPress is when the third party PCI compliance company (Securlity Metrics in my case), flags an application for security issues. Recently I needed to upgrade to PHP 7.6 with the latest version of WordPress. The PHP 7  upgrade was problematic in itself since many of the installed plugins in WordPress were not compatible with PHP 7. Long story short, upgrade when you absolutely have to. If you're using a web development company than you should be asking "why?". If it's not broke, you should have to upgrade it.

Comment: Thanks Jamie that was much as I'd hoped to hear. I'm not going mad then :)